# "Independently of one another" VS " in a state of independence of one another"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, exam-questions

> Similarly, vocal learners may have developed the ability independently **of one another**. (From the ACT)

What does the prepositional phrase "of one another" function as here? Modifying "independently"? Or something else?

I think it is better to use the noun form of "independently" such as "in a state of independence" or "in independence", thus "of one anther" serving as a complement for "independence."

Comment: Apart from identifying a brilliant Donna Summers song, the words [***State of Independence***](https://www.google.com/search?q=state+of+independence&oq=state+of+independence&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) aren't really used much in English. What you want in your context is definitely ***independently***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Independently of one another" sounds correct.
- "In a state of independence of one another" doesn't sound right - I believe it should be "in a state of independence from one another".

As a general rule we would say "independent *of*" something and "independence *from*" something. However, in your second example it uses "a state of independence" where it could just say "independent".

Comment: Thanks, so could I say sth like" XXX became independent of XXX" to mean that XXX gained independence from XXX?

Comment: @Charlie exactly.